# How javascript happen the same in chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript

This code in chrome happens in order but in safari It happens in the same and don't show the animation how can I fix it?(show the same in the safari)

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(window).on("click", ".small1", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(me).addClass("big");
    }, 1);
    window.open("http://google.com", "_self");
  });
```

Comment: 1 here means Millisecond and not second ... maybe you wish a second `1000` or something ... Just wondering ! And if you wish to have the `window.open` after timeout .. then you need to put that as well inside the `function)` of setTimeout ...

Comment: `setTimeout` uses Milliseconds, not seconds so `1000ms = 1s`. Fix that first or you won't even notice if there is a delay.

Comment: My problem isn't the time my prob is the order of execution at first gets big and then link open

Comment: @Arash since you only have 1ms of delay, you can't physicly see which one is executed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout takes Milliseconds as a parameter and not Seconds read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) , the section about setTimeout

> setTimeout() :    Calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds

... Additionally , if you wish the `window.open(..` to happen after the timeout finishes, you need to put it as well inside the `setTimeout`.

Please note that the timeout is only good for the function inside the `setTimeout`. Anything after the `setTimeout` statement executes asynchronously, so you'll have the `window.open` execute before the function inside `setTimeout` even started / finishes work.

So for instance ... the below should set the timeout to 1 second and also change the class and open the window after timeout expires.

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(window).on("click", ".small1", function() {
    me = this;
    $(me).addClass("big"); // First gets big, considering that the css has the desired effect in Safari.
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.open("http://google.com", "_self"); // Executes now after timeout finishes.
    }, 1000); // Timeout of one second.
  });
```

Sample snippet below :

```js
$(".small").on("click", function() {
  me = this;
  $(me).addClass("big");
  setTimeout(function(){
  window.open("http://google.com", "_self");},1000);
});
```

```css
.big {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small">myLink</div>
```

Comment: My goal is that div element gets big and then link open
but this happen only in chrome; safari don't do this and just open the link.

Comment: Why not check in safari if applying your class at all has any effect on the `".small1"` object that you clicked ...  then maybe move the `addClass` out of the `setTimeout` and only have `window.open` inside the `setTimeout` ... Also, maybe your css has no effect on the element that you are trying to add a class in safari ... verify those first.

Comment: I like to mark it but my reputation problem isn't solved

Comment: I'll do it immediately as I get that F reputation needed and do it for your other posts ;D

Comment:  this with more happiness